# Compass/Sass - Output two different themed CSS files

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, compass

I have two different sites that are essentially identical apart from the color scheme, and I use SCSS to generate the relevant CSS as follows:

```
$ui-theme: 'cba';

// CBA CORPORATE COLOURS
$cba_red:#C60750 !global;
$cba_green:#15AAB5 !global;
$cba_blue:#3B4358 !global;

// CLA CORPORATE COLOURS
$cla_red:#EE5E36 !global;
$cla_green:#CBDB2A !global;
$cla_blue:#00ACDC !global;

// SWITCH COLOUR THEME
@if $ui-theme == "cla" {
  $red:   $cla_red;
  $green: $cla_green;
  $blue:  $cla_blue;
} @else {
  $red:   $cba_red;
  $green: $cba_green;
  $blue:  $cba_blue;
}

// SCSS then follows, using $red, $green and $blue vars as appropriate
```

The SCSS is compiled to `css.css`, which I then copy to `cba.css`, change the `$ui-theme` var to `cla` and then recompile to make `css.css` again, which I then copy to `cla.css`.

My question is there a way to automate this, so that I can make compass output `cba.css` and `cla.css` directly, without me having to modify the input each time?

I also use grunt to run compass, so that may provide further options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- in your main scss file, replace the code you presented by just `@import colors.scss`
- create 2 files `cba.scss` and `cla.scss` with just your color definitions for that theme - for example `cla.scss`:

  ```
  $red:   #EE5E36 !global;
  $green: #CBDB2A !global;
  $blue:  #00ACDC !global;
  ```
- in grunt, to generate the cba theme do:

  1. copy `cba.scss` to `color.scss`
  2. call sass to compile your `main.scss`
- do the same for the cla theme.